# Give i+1 in for loop javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop in Javascript. How can I give the i+1 (last statement in for loop)? If I'm doing just `i+i`, the output is wrong.

```
for (var i=0; i<aantal; i++)
{
    strOutput += "<p><form action='' method='POST'>";
    strOutput += "<input class= 'nummers' type='number' name='aantal' min='1' max='20'>";
    strOutput += "<input type='submit' value='In mandje' name= 'toevoegen'>";
    strOutput += "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" + i +"'>";
}
```

Comment: i is automatically incremented at each iteration of the loop, I don't understand your problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: you could always do `for (var i=1; i<=aantal; i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
strOutput += "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" + (i+1) +"'>";
```

Answer (score 4):

You could increment your boundaries, since you don't use `i` for something else in this loop

```
for (var i = 1; i <= aantal; i++)
```